# .ajax() doesn't want to read xml data

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I created a folder named tp in htdocs then inside tp i created two file named balance.html and wrestler.xml. I made sure to open the file in browser with localhost/tp/balance.html and execute xampps program. But in balance.html the .ajax() doesn't want to retrieve the data from wrestler.xml.

this is the code from my html file :

```html
<script src="./jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'wrestler.xml',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function (xml) {
      console.log(xml);

    },
    error: function () {

      alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");

    }

  });
</script>
```

this  is my xml file :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<wrestler> 
<name>Modou</name>
<weight>100</weight>
</wrestler>
<wrestler2> 
<name>Modou</name>
<weight>150</weight>
</wrestler2>
```

Instead to get the data from my xml file I receive the error An error occurred while processing XML file.

edit: i add also the jquery library file.

Comment: I'm not an xml expert, but that doesn't look like valid xml?

Comment: I agree, it's not valid. It's missing the root node that contains all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

The XML is invalid, because it's missing the root node.

If you add a root node around all the wrestlers, it becomes valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<wrestlers>
  <wrestler>
    <name>Modou</name>
    <weight>100</weight>
  </wrestler>
  <wrestler2>
    <name>Modou</name>
    <weight>150</weight>
  </wrestler2>
</wrestlers>
```

I think it's also unusual to use incremented tag names like `<wrestler2>`, although it's valid. Typically all the children of `<wrestlers>` would be `<wrestler>`.

There are many online XML validators, which you can find with Google. You should paste your XML into one of them.